# Dynamically add a prop to Reactjs material ui Select

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-props, react-component

I have a question about the material UI Select component and how to set props dynamically.

I'm trying to wrap the material UI Select (https://material-ui.com/components/selects/) component in my CompanySelect so I can add some additional styling and other stuff.

#### Main question

How can I dynamically add/remove the disableUnderline prop on the material UI Select component.

When I set disableUnderline = null and variant = 'outlined' I get a warning that disableUnderline is an unknown prop. when using variant = 'standard' there is no warning.

#### CompanySelect component code

```
import React from 'react';
import Select from '@material-ui/core/Select';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import ExpandMoreRoundedIcon from '@material-ui/icons/ExpandMoreRounded';
import './style.scss';

const CompanySelect= (props) => {
  const {
    variant,
    disableUnderline,
    children,
    ...
  } = props;

  return (
    <Select
      disableUnderline={disableUnderline}
      variant={variant}
      ...
    >
      {children}
    </Select>
  );
};

CompanySelect.propTypes = {
  variant: PropTypes.oneOf(['outlined', 'filled', 'standard']),
  disableUnderline: PropTypes.bool,
  children: PropTypes.oneOfType([PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.node), PropTypes.node]).isRequired
};

CompanySelect.defaultProps = {
  variant: 'standard',
  disableUnderline: null,
};


export default CompanySelect;
```

#### Standard usage

```
<AtriasSelect variant="standard" disableUnderline>
  <MenuItem />
  <MenuItem />
</AtriasSelect>
```

#### Outlined usage

```
<AtriasSelect variant="outlined">
  <MenuItem />
  <MenuItem />
</AtriasSelect>
```

The standard usage works. With the disableUnderline the default underline is removed as documented on the Input API page. (https://material-ui.com/api/input/).

Problem occurs when I use the outlined variant because then the Select inherits the OutlinedInput API. If you look at the OutlinedInput API (https://material-ui.com/api/outlined-input/) then you can see it does not have the disableUnderline prop.

I gave the disableUnderline prop the default value 'null' assuming it would not render when not supplied. But when using the Outlined variant (without disableUnderline prop) I get the following warning.

```
React does not recognize the `disableUnderline` prop on a DOM element. If you intentionally want it to appear in the DOM as a custom attribute, spell it as lowercase `disableunderline` instead. If you accidentally passed it from a parent component, remove it from the DOM element.
```

So my question, is there a way to not add the prop at all. Something like the following pseudo code:

```
return (
  <Select
    {variant !== 'outlined' ? disableUnderline : null} //Pseudo code, just to show what I need
    variant={variant}
    ...
  >
    {children}
  </Select>
);
```

#### Possible solution

The only solution I see now (my react knowledge is limited) is adding an if statement in the CompanySelect component that will check if the outlined variant is used or not. But this means I need to have a lot of duplicate code in the CompanySelect code.

```
const CompanySelect= (props) => {
  const {
    variant,
    disableUnderline,
    children,
    ...
  } = props;

  if (variant !== 'outlined'){
    return (<Select disableUnderline={disableUnderline} variant={variant} ...> {children} </Select>);
  } else {
    return (<Select variant={variant} ...> {children} </Select>);
  }
};
```

Is there maybe another way of solving this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use spread operator (...) in returned JSX like this:

```
const CompanySelect= (props) => {
  const {
    variant,
    disableUnderline,
    children,
    ...
  } = props;

  return (
    <Select
      variant={variant}
      {...(variant !== "outlined" && { disableUnderline: true })}
    >
      {children}
    </Select>
  );
};
```

Comment: I changed your code to `{...(variant !== "outlined" && { disableUnderline: disableUnderline })}` otherwise the underline is always disable when variant != 'outlined'. Thanks for the one-line solution

Comment: @Reggi You’re right, that was a typo. You’re welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I think the proper way is to use [`React.cloneElement`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#cloneelement)

Something like

```
let props = {
    variant: variant,
};

// Your dynamic props
if(variant !== 'outlined') {
    props[disableUnderline] = 'your value';
}

<div>
 {
    React.cloneElement(
     Select,
     props
    )
 }
</div>
```